# How to get a request on controller for endpoint which is defined as default servlet-mapping on web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, controller, web.xml

I am working on a server where we are using a third party API provider for a particular service. The third party send a image endpoint. Eg. `"/media/image/image.jpg"`. The image is available on the third party base URL.

I need to make the image available on our base url. For that I have a controller.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/media/movie/{imageName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getMovieImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String type = imageName.split(".")[imageName.split("\\.").length - 1];
    String imageUrl = getBaseUrl() + imageName;
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.setContentType("image/" + type);
    ImageIO.write(image, type, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

But the problem is `*.jpg` is defined as a default servlet mapping on web.xml.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

So the request don't get to the controller and shows 404.

How can I get the request on my controller or is there any alternative way to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter's init parameter `excludedUrls` and check in filter if it isn't in exclsion list. See [full example](https://www.programmergate.com/how-to-exclude-a-url-from-a-filter/)

> ```
> if(!excludedUrls.contains(path))
> ```