# Spring security: how do I stop the chain with my custom code?

Tags: spring, spring-security

So, I have defined my custom filter and now I want to return in case something goes wrong:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     if(rulefail()){
        //what now??
      }

     filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
 }
```

I tried throwing a runtime exception but of course it isn't effective: the server returns the tomcat's default internal server error page.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer, just return or don't do filterChain.dofiler. See if this answer suffice https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445927/905494