# Jsf2.0 preRenderView

Tags: jsf-2

i am using jsf 2.0

i have question accoring to PreRenderView.

in my Bean i have method like

```
public void init() throws Exception
    {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/To My Page");
        if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback())
        {
            System.out.println("Kshitij");
        }
    }
```

when this method is executing it is also printing "Kshitij" in servler log.

then redirecting to page.

why? i think it has to redirect to page first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that the actual redirect is performed first? The method has to finish running first before the server can ever continue the control over the request/response. It's impossible to pause code execution halfway and then continue code execution at exactly the same location in a **brand new** request and thread.

The `redirect()` call basically sets the `Location` response header. Only when the method has returned, the server will send the response and then the browser will send a new request on that location.

Add a return statement or an if/else if you want to skip the printing when you need to redirect.

```
if (youNeedToRedirect) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/To My Page");
}
else {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        System.out.println("Kshitij");
    }
}
```

This all has got nothing to do with JSF or `preRenderView`. It's all just basic Java and HTTP.

#### Related:

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot (forward | sendRedirect | create session) after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe/2125045#2125045)

Comment: Thank you. good Answer. now i understand whay we are using return;