# JSP redirect through servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect

I have some problems with redirection in jsp app.

My redirect method is like this:

```
public static void redirectUrl(String url,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    request.getSession().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/" + url).forward(request,response);
}
```

When I start the app on localhost everything works fine but when I deployed it on the server it crash with this exception:

```
Servlet error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.EvermindHttpServletResponse.resetBuffer(EvermindHttpServletResponse.java:1933)
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:221)
at app.framework.request.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:835)
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:341)
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:230)
at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.GetParametersRequestDispatcher.forward(GetParametersRequestDispatcher.java:257)
```

I put return statement after every redirect call but it won't work.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide code that shows how you are calling this method from elsewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed
```

This error comes when response has already written.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe) in this post.

The term redirecting" you are using is not redirect as per your code.Its called "forwarding".

Try:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/" + url).forward(request, response);
```

EDIT (DetailedExplanation) :

`request.getRequestDispatcher(“url”)` means the dispatch is relative to the current HTTP request.

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
```

The path parameter doesn't have to start with a "/"

`getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(“url”)` means the dispatch is relative to the root of the `ServletContext`.

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispObj = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ContextRoot/home.jsp");
```

The path parameter has to start with a "/"

Comment: Yes I have already saw this post but doesn't help me. Why? Because I found all place where I use rediect method and put after it return. I think something else isn't not right.

Comment: @JordanBorisov: Can you provide some more code.The code which you have provided is not sufficient to identify the cause.

Comment: OK I think I found the problem I have to use request.getRequestDispatcher... to work properly : see the url bellow:  http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/difference-between-forward-and.html

Comment: @JordanBorisov: Good to hear that. I have added a difference of what you were trying previous.