# JSP Run Time Exception

Tags: jsp

IlligalStackException in JSP.  While we try to execute the response.sendRedirect() method in JSP file( whith error Message "Response already commited").

Comment: What is your question? Show your servlet/JSP code.

Answer (score 0):

That is a typically error message after you have already send a redirect and to output more data to the stream. That is impossible.

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe)

Comment: there is no applicationserver which is able to write output after the response is finished. Show us your jsp and we can try to find a solution for that.