# How to solve "Cannot forward. Response already committed" error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe)

```
  <% response.sendRedirect(submit_success);

  %>
```

I am trying to send redirect to a JSP file after processing my form.

I see execptions in my console ->  Cannot forward. Response already committed.Why do I get this error and what should I do to solve this?

[10/1/12 17:35:03:257 EDT] 0000022f servlet       E `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /SubmitContentProcess.jsp in application dwsecure. Exception created : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:67)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:139)
        at com.ibm._jsp._SubmitContentProcess._jspService(_SubmitContentProcess.java:233)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:17`

Comment: Don't abuse a JSP as controller. That logic belongs in a servlet.

Comment: Don't try to forward after sending a response?

Comment: I am trying to convert the servlet code to JSP scriptlet. What can I do instead? When I submit it should redirect me to success page.

Comment: Why are you converting a servlet to a JSP? That's a step backwards and falls under "using the wrong tool for the job".

Comment: We have a code freeze where we can't deploy class files. While JSP can be easily deployed without getting approvals. I am actually coding a similar page like the existing one.To ensure my code is working, I am rewriting the servelet to a jsp.

Comment: I am writing a JSP (form) which calls another jsp to process on form submit. It has to redirect to success jsp after the submission is successful.

Comment: Well,  This was a management decision anyways. I would prefer to get some suggestions/answers from you :)