# Cause of IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe)

What is the usual cause of this kind of error:

```
com.mycompany.myapp.servlet.TxnDetailsServlet doRequest
ERROR: View failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.servlet.TxnDetailsServlet.doRequest(TxnDetailsServlet.java:82)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.servlet.TxnDetailsServlet.doGet(TxnDetailsServlet.java:131)
```

The servlet process the request (i.e set attributes) then call:

```
    private void doRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException     {
        // Code omitted
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Some.jsp").forward(this.request, this.response);
        // Code omitted
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(request, response);
        doRequest(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(request, response);
        doRequest(request);
    }
```

The servlet does not do anything in reponse.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet of `TxnDetailsServlet` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add to what others said, response need not be transferred to client(browser) in a single shot. Instead it can be transferred to client in multiple shots as, whenever you call a response.flushBuffer . Once the response starts transferring data to client, you cant do anything that changes response state(setStatus, forward etc)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write to the response output stream if you forward to another servlet/jsp.