# session.invalidate() is sometimes not working and not destroying the session object. What should I do?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, httpsession

```
Public class Logout extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.invalidate();

        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
        
    }
}
```

I am doing this in eclipse on Apache Tomcat server. When I restart the server sometimes the session object deletes but majority times it does not. In new browser I can still fetch the details after session.invalidate() is called.

I tried many other things like -

- a return statement after RequestDispatcher.
- and i even tried the below code as well -

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  
 if (session != null) 
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);
```

Nothing worked for me ;)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/13972697/6505250 answer your question (`resp.sendRedirect("/index.html");` instead of `forward` after `session.invalidate()`)?

Comment: Indeed. The session is still present in current request. You need to create a new request by sending a redirect.

Comment: Don't use a request session object, because you cannot reuse it after the session is invalidated. You can check the session is valid, otherwise redirect browser to login page.