# Redirect to another servlet in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having troubles of directing to another servlet in a servlet file. I have a servlet file called `NewDreamServlet.java` and I want to redirect it to `MyDreamsServlet.java`.

This is what I currently have in the `NewDreamServlet.java` for redirecting.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyDreamsServlet").forward(request, response);
```

When I call this it ends up going to a blank page,

```
http://localhost:8080/ps10-austint/NewDreamServlet
```

How exactly would I accomplish this? Please let me know if there is any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try: `response.sendRedirect("/YourApp/MyDreamsServlet")`

Comment: `HTTP Status 404 - /MyDreamsServlet` I am getting this, my servlet file is under Java Resources->src->dreams->MyDreamServlet.java. Is there a specific way to path that? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Try my edited answer.. I wasn't sure if it would append YourApp twice like so: `YourApp/YourApp/MyDreamsServlet`

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /ps10-austint/ps10-austint/MyDreamsServlet It looks like it appended it twice.

Comment: Did you configure the name of the servlet in the web.xml file? If not, then the original answer was probably right.

Comment: What do you mean configure the name? Haha sorry. The display-name?

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDreamsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyDreams</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Yes it works now, Thank you I appreciate it. I will vote as the answer after 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `response.sendRedirect("/MyDreamsServlet")`. Also, please note that you might have to add an return statement. The following post discusses this in more details [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot (forward | sendRedirect | create session) after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe/2125045#2125045)

Answer (score 0):

All these answers to your question are wrong.
1. if you like to use RD().forward, which is more used for with in application calls, all you need to do is go to your web.xml file and for the url part of your 2nd servlet give it any name you would like eg. /fireServletTwo....
Now come back to your 1st servlet and in the getRqstDispatcher braces, write("/fireServletTwo"); this will tell the xml file to look for a servlet mapping with that name and run that servlet.
2. if you would like to use send.Redirect(); which takes a URL and is used to mostly pass controls outside of the application to another domain, its simple.. DO NOT USE A SLASH /.... just write the name of your servlet2 inside "";

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me but it usually better to have the context path:

```html
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/home.jsp");
```