# IllegalStateException on LogoutServlet

Tags: java, servlets, logout

I'm trying to implement a logout servlet in cq5, where I need to logout my users from a cas server and cq5.
The problem is that I need the servlet to both logout from cq5 and then redirect to the cas logout page, but since I'm using a response to do both these things I get an IllegalStateException.

Any idea on how to do this?

This is my servlet code:

```
import com.stuff.etc.*;

@Component( metatype = false)
@SlingServlet(
        methods = {"GET"},
        generateComponent = false        
)
@Service
public class MyLogoutServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {   

    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private Authenticator authenticator;

    public static final String PAR_USER = "username";

    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths")
    public static final String SERVLET_PATH = "/system/mysite/logout";

    @Property(name = "sling.auth.requirements", propertyPrivate = true)
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String[] AUTH_REQUIREMENT = { "-" + SERVLET_PATH };

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CookieStoreUtil.class);  

    public static final String TOKEN_COOKIE_ID = "mysite_auth";

    private static final String LOGOUT_RESOURCE = "https://casurl.com/logout";

    @Reference
    private CryptoSupport cryptoSupport;

    @Reference
    private SlingSettingsService settingsService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,   SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter(PAR_USER);                       

        final Authenticator authenticator = this.authenticator;
        log.info(String.valueOf(authenticator==null));

        if(username != null) {
            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Request to logout user: " + username);
            }
            request.removeAttribute(WSCAuthToken.TOKEN_ATTR_USER);
            WSCAuthToken token = getAuthToken(request, cryptoSupport);

            //if(token != null && token.isDebugMode()) {
            if(token != null) {
                token.setUser(null);
                token.resetAttributes();
                saveAuthCookie(request, response, cryptoSupport, token);

                CookieStoreUtil.resetStoreCookie(request, response, settingsService);               
                TokenCookie.setCookie(response, TOKEN_COOKIE_ID, "", -1, "/", null, false, request.isSecure());

                if (authenticator != null) {
                    try {
                        log.info("SIAMO QUI");
                        log.info("ANDIAMO QUI: "+request.getContextPath());
                        AbstractAuthenticationHandler.setLoginResourceAttribute(request, request.getContextPath());
                        authenticator.logout(request, response);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                        log.error("service: Response already committed, cannot logout");
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    log.error("service: Authenticator service missing, cannot logout");
                }

            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);        
            }                           
        }   else {  
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Username non specificato");     
        }
        response.sendRedirect(LOGOUT_RESOURCE);
        //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }   

    public static WSCAuthToken getAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, CryptoSupport cryptoSupport) {
        WSCAuthToken token = null;

        Object tokenAttr = request.getAttribute(TOKEN_COOKIE_ID);
        if ((tokenAttr instanceof WSCAuthToken)) {          
            return (WSCAuthToken)tokenAttr;
        }

        String cookie = TokenCookie.getCookie(request, TOKEN_COOKIE_ID);                            

        if (cookie != null) {
            String value;
            try {
                value = cryptoSupport.unprotect(cookie);
                token = WSCAuthToken.fromJSON(value);
            } catch (CryptoException e) {
                log.error("CryptoException getting token: " + e.getMessage());
            }           
        }
        return token;
    } 

    public static void saveAuthCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            CryptoSupport cryptoSupport, WSCAuthToken token) {

        try {           
            request.setAttribute(token.getCk(), token);
            String value = cryptoSupport.protect(token.toJSON());           
            TokenCookie.setCookie(response, TOKEN_COOKIE_ID, "\"" + value + "\"", -1, "/", null, true, request.isSecure());         
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            log.error("CryptoException saving cookie", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException saving cookie", e);
        }   
    }
}
```

The log for the error:
    `02.08.2013 11:03:23.966 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1375434203945] GET /system/sorgeniabpp/logout HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable java.lang.IllegalStateException: response already committed`

Also another problem is that I don't even get to logout from CQ5. I've tried to merge my servlet with the code implemented on org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.LogoutServlet but with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add *return* statement even after *sendError*(As already @suresh atta told you that you need to add *return* statement after *redirection*).
Accroding to [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) and [HttpServletResponse#sendError](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int))

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException.After using this method, the response should be 
>   considered to be committed and should not be written to.

So return statement after *sendError* also.

```
 response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED); 
 return;
```

and

```
 response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Username non specificato");
 return;
```

with this

```
 response.sendRedirect(LOGOUT_RESOURCE);
 return;
```

For more details about [why you need to add return statement after redirect or sendError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return`  statement  after the redirection,So that it stops adding further content to the `response`.

```
  response.sendRedirect(LOGOUT_RESOURCE);
  return;
```

> The server has [already finished](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=5180) writing the response header and is writing the body of the content, and which point you are trying to write more to the header - of course it cant rewind.

Comment: can please post the `stacktrace` ?