# forward and sendRedirect issue. "Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed"

Tags: jsp, servlets, response.redirect, forward

i want to implement this..
In my page1.jsp i have a link and the link triggers a servlet

```
    <a href="Servlet">link1</a>
```

So, when the user press the link1, the servlet among other things i want to do two things.
**1** Pass to the next page page2.jsp an object and 
**2** redirect the user to the page2.jsp
In the Servlet i wrote:

```
     request.setAttribute("cis", myObjet);
     RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/page2.jsp");
     disp.forward(request, response);
     response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
```

After i run the application, i get an error in console that says:

> Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

i read some topics relevant to this, but i havent solve it. Also the application continue to work, although i have this error in the console... thank you a lot!

Comment: Why have you added the `sendRedirect`, given that you are already forwarding to the same page?

Comment: well you have right!! it worked.. Submit it as an answer if you want, to accept it.. thx @RohitJain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't call `sendRedirect()`, after you have already used `forward()`. So, you get that exception.

However, it seems like the use of `sendRedirect()` there is really not needed. You seem to be believing that you need to use `sendRedirect()` after `forward()`, since you have used the same page in both of them. Actually, it's not like that.

Simply remove the `sendRedirect` line, and you'll be fine.

**See also:**

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot (forward | sendRedirect | create session) after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2123514/1679863)

Comment: in my case checking for null pointer exception and fixing it by avoiding that scenario altogether fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

if you have to more than one redirect lines which checks conditions each own, to not get exception you should control the response is committed.

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) getResponse();

if (!response.isCommitted()){
// redirect or dispatch whereever you want
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally wrong. You can't do a redirect after a forward or vice versa. You can do either forward or redirect.

Read up these links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

http://javapapers.com/jsp/difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect/

Hope this helps.

Sahil

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the combination of rd.include(req,res); and res.sendRedirect(-); at the same time but you can't with the combination of rd.forward(req,res); and res.sendRedirect(-); at the same time.  Because both the forwards to the new page.