# in jsp response.sendRedirect() is not working

Tags: jsp, session

This is my code

```
HttpSession s=request.getSession(false);
if(s==null)
{
    System.out.println("123456");
    response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}
System.out.println(s);
s.setAttribute("vid",request.getParameter("v"));
System.out.println(request.getParameter("v"));
new action.VideoAction().vPlay(request);
```

123456 is getting printed but the response.sendRedirect() is not working and the s.setAttribute() is giving error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe)

Comment: @BalusC that's a question about `forward` not about `sendRedirect`

Comment: Problem has the same grounds. OP is expecting `sendRedirect()` call to magically stop the code.

Comment: @BalusC yep - which means that the answer is similar - not the question :)

Comment: Who says that OP is smart enough to look in server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `return` after you sendRedirect:

```
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
return;
```