# Getting null value on request.getAttribute

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I have a servlet class like this

```
public class DBConnection extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
   {

      resp.setContentType("text/html");
      req.setAttribute("Message","Message from servlet page");

      req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req,resp);

   }
}
```

calling servlet on index.jsp page like this

```
<% String Msg= (String)request.getAttribute("Message");
out.println("<p> Servlet communicated message to JSP: "+ Msg + "</p>");%>
```

This in my web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>dbconnection</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.html
    </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DBConnection</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>DBConnection</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DBConnection</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DBConnection</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting a null value .. can anyone help me?

Comment: reading this might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2125045/1851302

Comment: Can you show me your URL. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the attributes defined in the servlet using Expression Language.

Inside JSP:

```
<p> Servlet communicated message to JSP: ${Message} </p>
```

Servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
resp.setContentType("text/html");
req.setAttribute("Message","Message from servlet page");
rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
rd.forward(req,resp);
```

Comment: still getting the null value

Comment: Sorry, when you said you were getting a null value I though you could see the page but not the message.
Make sure you have full for <servlet-class>DBConnection</servlet-class>
If DBConnection is inside a package, you need to specify that. eg. pack.com.DBConnection

Comment: Also the url pattern should be either accessed through the address bar or linked to by a form for example.
'<form method="POST" action="DBConnection"><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null value because you are not accessing with right url.

Suppose you have url like following:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/
```

where your project name is `TestWeb`. If you had tried with above url you are getting `null` value because request is not comming from servlet. So you need to use like following url

```
http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/DBConnection
```

Then only you will get right output. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. there is a mistake in accessing right url

Comment: @user123. Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your servlet in url that you are trying to invoke
Try as suggested by Yubi.

Example: If your url pattern is

```
<url-pattern>/TestingServlet</url-pattern>
```

in your `web.xml` to execute your servlet get/post in that servlet u should use urlpattern

```
    `http://yourserverhost:port/ServletTest/TestingServlet`
```

**ServletTest** is your application context and **TestingServlet** is your url pattern for your Servlet.

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TestingServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>TestingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestingServlet</servlet-name>
    **<url-pattern>/TestingServlet</url-pattern>**
  </servlet-mapping>
```