# How to return Jersey MVC Viewable after authentication redirect?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, single-sign-on, openid-connect

TLDR: My method requires 2 redirects/forwards to work (1 for authentication and 1 to serve the jsp page). How can I resolve both redirects/forwards (or make it a non-requirement) so as to not run into the error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.

For more context:

I have a java servlet with a method that looks something like the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Authenticate
public Viewable test(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    Map<String, Object> model = createModel();
    return new Viewable("/somePath/jspFile", model);
}
```

The @Authenticate annotation intercepts the call to do some [Open ID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) type authentication which results in the user being forwarded to a different server for all authentication needs. If the user is authenticated, they are redirected back to my application.

However, when hitting the url for this method, I am getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed**. I don't know too much about using this [Viewable](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/Viewable.html) class, but based on the fact that I don't run into that error when returning String/void/whatever else, I assume returning a new Viewable needs to do some forwarding that results in the user seeing the jsp page.

I've read the main [SO post about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-sendredirect-create-session), but I am unsure how to apply the fixes to my current problem. For example, I don't know how I would apply something like the following fix:

```
protected void doPost() {
    if (someCondition) {
        sendRedirect();
    } else {
        forward();
    }
}
```

The fix assumes that I can I can either redirect OR forward, but my current method needs a redirect for authentication AND a forward/redirect to serve the jsp page. Maybe there's an obvious fix I'm missing that doesn't require a complete rehaul of the current code?

<s>Edit: It would be nice if I could check if the user was authenticated first, but I assume using this annotation at all automatically entails an initial redirect</s>

Edit: It looks like the user is redirected for the initial login authentication, but does not need to be redirected again after being authenticated once due to [SSO](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on some preliminary testing, it seems like the following solution has worked for me:

1. Check if the user has already been authenticated
2. Return a Response rather than a Viewable.

Since the user only needs to be redirected the first time for authentication, I can return an empty/meaningless response as a placeholder. And then once the user has been authenticated and is returned to my app, I can return a Viewable wrapped in a Response object.

So the code would look something like the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Authenticate
public Response test(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse 
response) {
    Map<String, Object> model = createModel();
    if (userIsAuthenticated()) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/somePath/jspFile", model)).build();
    }
}
```