# How to use ExternalDirectory Resource

Tags: spring, jsp, jboss

How to use External Directory to Store Images.

And how i access that images thru my Web application ?

- I am using Jboss as an application Server.
- Web application is in Java,Jsp.
- Presently images stored in WAR file.

After google i got the solution

C:\jboss-4.0.0\server\default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar\server.xml

Then restart the server and access the

http://localhost:8080/contextname/images

Please provide comments

Comment: Your question is tagged `spring`, but there's no mention of it in your description... is it a Spring MVC app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered similar question before: [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java-w)

To summarize there are basically two ways:

1. Add a new `Context` to the `server.xml` denoting the absolute location where the images are.
2. Create a `Servlet` which gets an `InputStream` of the image using `FileInputStream` and writes it the usual Java IO way to the `OutputStream` of the response, along with at least `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and `Content-Disposition` headers.

See the link for more detailed answers and code examples.