# Java: how to write to folder in webapp?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I deployed my webapp in Tomcat, but when I prefix the filename with \ I end up in the root of my server (C) folder, and if I don't prefix it with \ I end up in the bin folder.
The former I expected, the latter I didn't.
What's the cleanest way to write to a folder in my webapp(userControlWebApp\images) because just doing ..\webapps\ `+ request.getContextPath()` doesn't seem the cleanest way.

Comment: Can't you use an absolute path?

Comment: That's well so absolute... I like to keep it a bit dynamic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `getServletContext().getRealPath(..)`

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that one. Just tried System.getProperty("user.dir") and that also seems to work. Any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: prefer the API - getRealPath. I'm not sure if the other is guaranteed to work always.

Comment: Note that the folder and all its contents will get lost whenever you redeploy the webapp. It's not a good choice if you want to make it permanent. See also this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548190/best-location-for-uploading-file/4548320#4548320