# Getting the upload folder in a Java servlet container

Tags: spring, war, multipartform-data

Could be a silly question, but...

I have a Spring-based WAR application that runs 80% of the installations on Tomcat and the rest 20% on WebSphere.

I need to simply get the path of the folder where Spring's `MultipartFilter` (using Commons multipart resolver) stores files being uploaded. I have never set it manually, and it actually belongs to the Catalina work directory as I found out in my Tomcat installations.

For the moment, I just need to get that path. I have control of my application so no one is going to change it without notice.

I would like to know if there is a server-agnostic way to know where my Spring-based application is going to store Multipart files.

E.g. from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548190/best-location-for-uploading-file) I can see I can use `catalina.base`, but in Tomcat... not in JBoss or WebSphere. It could cost me a couple of if/else statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring tries to do it already *when no default value is set*

```
WebUtils.getTempDir(servletContext)
```

Which simply does:

```
return ((File)servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir"));
```

So simply if no one overrides that location in the filter properties (and that is my case) I can rely on the default.

More in general, one may have to inspect the instance of `DiskItemFileFactory` to get the path to the `repository`