# Get absolute path of "web content" folder in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, absolute-path

I want to get the absolute path of `Web content` folder in source code so I can retrieve another folder to upload file.

I tried `ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("images")` to get the folder image in source code.

**Expected result should be**:

> "C:\Learning\Workspace\Eclipse\boxingsaigon\WebContent\images".

But it returns me where the web was deployed:

**Actual result is**:

> "C:\Learning\Workspace\Eclipse.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\boxingsaigon\images".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to be clear so people can understand thing like What are you getting, what are you expecting and what's wrong with current one.

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: try this `String path=application.getRealPath("/DBBACKUP/EXPORT/dbexport.sql");` here `/DBBACKUP/EXPORT/` is folders in my web project

Comment: That's because from the looks of it, it's picking up from where it expanded the war file.

Comment: @AtulNar There's no application object. Please help me to double check. thanks

Comment: @AnhNguyen i use this code in jsp btw where you want to get path in servlet or jsp page ??

Comment: @AtulNar i want to get it in servlet.

Comment: where your upload folder going to be ??

Comment: @AtulNar it's "C:\Learning\Workspace\Eclipse\boxingsaigon\WebContent\images" and the source code folder is C:\Learning\Workspace\Eclipse\boxingsaigon

Comment: this link could help [absolute-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517401/get-absolute-path-to-apache-webcontents-folder-from-a-java-class-file?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to get absolute path is right. You can get the full path by

```
ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("images");
```

but you get path `C:\Learning\Workspace\Eclipse.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\boxingsaigon\images` is the path where your actual web application is deployed.

If you change the deployed path to tomcat webapps directory that it gives you path to that directory.
you can to get the path where your actual source code is reside.

[From Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 ServletContext.getRealPath() returns the absolute file path on the server's 
 filesystem would be served by a request for
 "http://host/contextPath/index.html", where contextPath is the 
 context path of this ServletContext..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
public String getRealFile(HttpServletRequest request, String path) {
  return request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(path);
}
```

Hope this helps.