# Dynamically add .xhtml file in webapp folder

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, filewriter

I want to dynamically add new `.xhtml` files in the webapp folder of my project.
It only works when i give the full path like,

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:/projects/UIBindingExample/src/main/webapp/pagefour.xhtml");
            fw.write("<html>...some code....</html>");

            fw.close();
```

instead of this  i want to get it work using the relative path of the file like,

```
src/main/webapp/pagefour.xhtml
```

i tried this.but its not working .!!!
what should i do?
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/primeface-update-after-upload/8889096#8889096

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/webapp/pagefour.xhtml` is a relative path to the context of your webapp, so probably if you run this code you would end up in saving file contents to `D:/projects/UIBindingExample/target/your-artifact-name/WEB-INF/main/webapp/pagefour.xhtml`

where `your-artifact-name` is name of generated WAR file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: then the file is created in the following  path

`D:\program\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1`

Comment: Depends on where or how you run your webapp. I assumed that you are using embedded container ran via Maven, like jetty:run.