# Reading/writing a text file in a servlet, where should this file be stored in JBoss?

Tags: servlets, jboss

I have servlet deployed in JBoss. I want to read/write data into a text file based on the client input. Where should this text file be put in the JBoss directory structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There the `/data` directory is for.

[image]

---

Its absolute path is available by the `jboss.server.data.dir` system property.

```
File dataDir = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"));
File yourFile = new File(dataDir, "filename.ext");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [JBoss Wiki - JBoss Properties](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties)

Note that you're this way tight-coupling the web application code to a specific server. If you ever want to change servers, keep in mind to change the above code as well to whatever the new server supports (or not).

Comment: Is the system property "jboss.server.data.dir" already present in the jboss jre?

Comment: Yes, it's set by JBoss itself, but it's overridable by a manual `-Djboss.server.data.dir` VM argument.

Comment: I also have images to be displayed in my jsp pages which are deployed in jboss. I put the images in the  .war file outside the WEB-INF directory along with the jsp files. the jsp files are not showing the pictures. Should I put the images in the data directory also? What should I do?

Comment: I don't get you. Should I speciy the abolute path of the images. What I have done referred the image with its name in the jsp page since both the jsp and the images are in the same directory.

Comment: You just didn't give sufficient information to point out the real cause, so I can't give a more detailed answer. If an image don't show up, then its URL is wrong. Simple as that. I can only add the hint that any HTML page resource URLs are resolved relative to the request URL (as you see in browser address bar). So if your JSP happen to be requested through a virtual URL for example, then the image URL should be altered based on that.

Comment: Okay I will explain in detail. I have a 'tmp'. Inside it, there are jsp files and some images(to be used as the background in the jsp files-the path is just the name of the image). inside the tmp folder, there is also a 'WEB-INF' folder which contains the web.xml. Now I went to the 'tmp' foldr and made war file of all the contents of the tmp folder- 'hello.war'. Then I put this 'hello.war' in the deploy directory of the jboss. And then went to the url locahost:8080/hello/xyz.jsp.     But only the the textual contents of the jsp file is being displayed and the images are not.

Comment: @BalusC Could you tell me please where I can information about this but in JBoss AS 7.1?

Comment: @JohnB: The same environment variables are available. Only folder structure has changed; it's now all in `/standalone`. See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters

Comment: Thanks @BalusC I just found too. Always, you are the greatest one