# Refresh an uploaded image in JSF(to display)

Tags: image, jsf, upload, refresh

I'm developing a JSF application which has an image upload function. I'd like to display the uploaded image. The uploading works fine but when I delete the uploaded picture and upload a new one, the old one is displayed in the browser. I typed the link of the picture in the browser but I sill get the old one. I use the same file name and I would not like to change it. How could I refresh it. (without Javascript). I'm using Glassfish Server. (Redeplyoing the application I get the new picture but it isn't a solution for an online system ;))
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Redeplyoing the application I get the new picture*

Don't store it in the deploy folder by `getRealPath()` and consorts. Store it **outside** the deploy folder.

#### See also:

- [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/primeface-update-after-upload/8889096#8889096)

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I changed the code, it was very useful. Unfortunately the problem is still exists. I have to refresh the page manually in the browser after the file is uploaded.