# h:graphicImage is not downloaded when its value is updated through f:ajax

Tags: ajax, image, jsf, facelets, mojarra

I have an image component on a page:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/imageServlet?imageId=#{someBean.imageId}"/>
```

And down in the page I have a commandLink that contains:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all"></f:ajax>
```

When I click on the commandlink, all sections in the page get updated. This also includes the `src` of image. So, I can see in firebug that the `h:graphicImage` gets successfully updated.

Now, the problem is, even though `src` is updated, the new image is not downloaded from the server, and therefore I get an 'X' where the image was supposed to appear. When I right click on the image and click 'view image', it is successfully downloaded.

My question is, is there some other way to update an `h:graphicImage` with ajax or is there some other measure I need to take to complete the intended behaviour?

**Note:** *I am on Mojarra 2.1.6, Tomcat 7 and I'm not using any third party component suite.*

Thanks,

Serkan

Comment: possible duplicate of [PrimeFace update after upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/primeface-update-after-upload)

Comment: thanks for the pointer @BalusC but that seems to be a different use case. in my case, the image component is requesting an already existing image (through the image servlet and image servlet - when accessed - responds with a correct image with correct mime types etc). the ajax command basically updates the page, the component (when loaded) requests a url among existing ones, and I can see that the src is updated (although image not requested by the browser)

Comment: Hmm OK, thus the ajax response returned a `<img src>` with a different `imageId` parameter value? Which browsers did you all tried?

Comment: Yes, src is updated. I tried IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari (all latest major versions)

Comment: just wanted to post a follow up on this, the issue remains open. I've worked around this by appending timestamp parameter at the end of the image url (src) using javascript. The js causes the image to reload from the new timestamped url. It is a dirty solution, but at least provides somewhat acceptable functionality

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am terribly stuck by this. The funny part is that it works absolutely fine on localhost. I saw my logs for GAE and it shows that the image path is fine but Ajax can't load it properly on JSF screens.

Comment: @Aayush I could not solve it apart from the workaround I described in my prevoius comment.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a browser related issue. Have you tried disabling your browser cache?

Comment: I tried checking browser cache, it is not the problem. in fact this happens for images that has not been previously accessed by the browser. if an image is shown once, the problem does not occur on subsequent requests of the same image. also, I tried this with IE, FF, Chrome, Safari all with same results