# How to display an pdf once uploaded with jsf

Tags: jsf

I have created a file upload function which saves all the uploads to a certain place:

```
private String destination = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FileUpload/uploadedDocuments/";
```

Is this a good place to store it? Should I store it some where else?

Is it possible that once the upload is complete for a page to be displayed showing the user what they have just uploaded, like a box below showing a preview? And how would I go about doing this? I am new.

I have figured it out how to display a plain txt file and an image, however it is the pdf that is confusing me.

Comment: What do you mean by "showing the user what they have just uploaded?". A link for download? A thumbnail? For the first option, you can use the regular download servlet or (if you want to stay JSF), use [this example](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2006/05/pdf-handling.html)

Comment: I was thinking, if possible their document displayed on the screen not, like a preview box if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

As to the upload location, which seems to be the IDE project folder, that's absolutely not right. You should choose a configureable and fixed location somewhere outside the IDE project folder. You should not rely on using `getRealPath()` or relative paths in `java.io.File`. It would make your webapp unportable. See also this related question: [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page).

Whatever way you choose based on the information provided in the answer of the aforementioned question (and all links therein), you should ultimately end up having a valid URL pointing to the PDF file in question such as http://example.com/files/some.pdf.

Then, you can serve the PDF file on a webpage using either an `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="/files/some.pdf" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
```

Or an `<object>`:

```
<object data="/files/some.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="400">
    <a href="/files/some.pdf">some.pdf</a> <!-- This link will only show up when the browser doesn't support showing PDF. -->
</object>
```

Keep in mind that showing PDFs in a browser is only supported in browsers having Adobe Reader plugin. Note that the `<object>` approach will gracefully degrade to a link when the browser doesn't support displaying `application/pdf` content.