# How to load an image from an external path in JSF page?

Tags: image, jsf, image-uploading, graphicimage

Hello once again i ask question on stackOverflow :)

I have a list of questions in my database , every question has an image that I upload with a `<p:fileupload>` specifying an external path like *C:\imgQuestions*, the backup works fine .

My problem is that I don't know how to display the image as it is in an external path. I tested this code on my JSF page but no result.

```
<p:graphicImage value="C:\imgQuestions\test.jpg" />
```

I found this discussion purpose but I did not understand how involved in my case.

[Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)

Any suggestion?

Thank you.