# Tomcat: uploaded image can only be obtained after restarting server

Tags: java, caching, tomcat, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)

I'm uploading an image to a folder 'images' inside my web context. Everything is working ok and I can see the image was correcly uploaded into that folder. 
However, after the upload I can't access that image using the url 'http://mywebapp/images/uploadedimage.png' (404)... Aparently, only after a server restart that resource is available, which of course is not suitable.
How can I fix this, is this a Tomcat cache issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8889096). Note: the question may not be exactly the same, but the answer definitely is. In a nutshell: do not write uploaded files to deploy folder!