# New uploaded files and Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

I have a simple servlet for images uploading, a user select an image and the servlet does its job and then write it to *upload* directory. My project layout:

```
project
    ├───static
    │   ├───img
    │   └───js
    ├───upload
    └───WEB-INF
        └───lib
```

After uploading the image, the user is redirected to it's location:

```
http://localhost:8080/upload/[image MD5 hash].png
```

The uploading code works pretty well, but Tomcat returns 404 error when requesting the url even when the image is there:

```
> wget http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2013-01-16 03:45:33--  http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-01-16 03:45:33 ERROR 404: Not Found.
>
```

After I click `update classes and resources` in my IDE, Intellij, it works:

```
> wget http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2013-01-16 03:48:11--  http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11666 (11K) [image/png]
Saving to: `f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png'

100%[==========================================================>] 11,666      --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-01-16 03:48:11 (72.9 MB/s) - `f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png' saved [11666/11666]
>
```

The second thing is that when I manualy delete this image, I still can download it (does Tomcat do some sort of cashing?):

```
> del f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
> wget http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2013-01-16 04:12:25--  http://localhost:8080/upload/f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11666 (11K) [image/png]
Saving to: `f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png'

100%[==========================================================>] 11,666      --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-01-16 04:12:25 (93.2 MB/s) - `f5d1da2cadf3bd1c1b9196ec522a5d73.png' saved [11666/11666]
>
```

My *web.xml* file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/upload/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Could someone please tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when deploy in development your resouce will deploy in development resource not workspace ,and  when you remove in workspace must redeploy for change in development resource

sory in my english,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow & Thank you so much!! I finally got it works. I just copied the war folder into Tomcat's webapps directory and It works great now :).

Comment: This is not how things are supposed to work. It would still fail if Tomcat is configured to not hotdeploy changes (like as most production setups would do as that's a quite expensive background task).

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to deal with file uploads. You should not store uploaded files in the deploy folder. You should for sure also not map the container-specific default servlet in webapp's own `web.xml`. You should store uploaded files in a fixed non-deploy-related folder elsewhere on the local disk file system publish it via a new `<Context>` in Tomcat. E.g.

```xml
<Context docBase="/var/webapp/upload" path="/upload" />
```

#### See also:

- [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096)