# I do not see the directory created ,while trying from a servlet . Why is that?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

The following is a servlet that attempts to create a directory and a text file inside that directory.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String s = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    FileMaker fm  = new FileMaker();
    fm.makeDirectoryTester();
}
```

---

*Class that makes a directory and a text file in it :*

```
public void makeDirectoryTester() {
    try {
        File f = new File("FlushTester/");
        if(!f.exists()) {
            boolean b = f.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory Made (Inside makeDirectoryTester) --> " + b);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("FlushTester/TESTER.txt");
            writer.println("This is the first statement");
            writer.println("This is the second statement");
            writer.println("This is the third statement");
            writer.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the boolean *f.mkdir()* returns `true` but I cannot see any directory created or any file inside it ! Why is that ? I am using tomcat as the server. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Where do you expect the file to be created? Which root directory?

Comment: You keep making the same major mistake. Don't do that. Read the links I posted in your previous related question(s). As to where it's been created, just print `File#getAbsolutePath()`. As to the concrete functional requirement: just stop using `getRealPath()` and relative paths in `File`. On a related note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream/2308388#2308388

Comment: @BalusC I didn't use `getRealPath()` in my code ! I was testing something and forgot to remove that, in the code I presented here.

Comment: @BalusC with reference to the [question i asked another day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563338/link-doesnt-work-when-i-access-it-via-localhost) is it fine to create directories the way I am creating in the above code so as to download later on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `File f = new File("FlushTester/");` the file is relative to the start point of your application. For tomcat that is usually the `bin` directory.

If you need it in some other place you should use absolute path (probably configured somehow), or a path relative to your tomcat's `bin` directory.