# Unable to load the image dynamically in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am working on some project, and i need to implement the image upload and view the image functionality,
but i am facing some problem here.

I am unable to display the image, can you please help me.

I am using p:fileload from primefaces, And i am storing all the images in bin folder of jboss server(E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\BrandImages\logo.gif). 
And storing that path in MYSQL DB, till now it is working fine. But when i am trying to display the image by calling getBrandDetails(), it is unable to display. Can you please tell me how can i solve this problem???

### In web.xml

In web.xml i added filter and mime...

### Xhtml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <h:panelGrid id="brandDetails_Panel" columns="2" columnClasses="plabel, pvalue" styleClass="ui-panelgrid">
        <h:outputLabel for="brand_img_url" value="Brand Image" />
    <p:fileUpload id="brand_img_url" fileUploadListener="#{brandBean.handleFileUpload}"  
        mode="advanced"  sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>

        <h:outputLabel value="" />
    <p:graphicImage value="#{brandBean.brand_image}" alt="The image could not be found."/>
    </h:panelGrid>
<f:facet name="footer" >
    <center>
        <p:commandButton id="add" value="Add"  disabled="#{brandBean.disable_addBut}" actionListener="#{brandBean.addBrandDetails}"/>
        <p:commandButton id="view" value="View" disabled="#{brandBean.disable_viewBut}"  action="#{brandBean.getBrandDetails}"/>         
    </center>       
</f:facet>
</h:form>
```

In addBrandDetails(), handleFileUpload() as

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) 
{
String t1=".\\BrandImages\\"+event.getFile().getFileName();
System.out.println("The final path is :"+t1);

try{
    File f =new File(t1);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bulk;
        InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        while (true) {
          bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
          if (bulk < 0) {
                 break;
                 }
          fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
          fileOutputStream.flush();
          }
          fileOutputStream.close();
          inputStream.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
}   

this.brand_image=t1;
}
```

In getBrandDetails(), i am setting as "this.setBrand_image(b.getBrand_img_url());"

When i am pringting it is printing path E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\BrandImages\logo.gif

but it is unable to display the image.

Please help me out....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your bean must have the scope as session. A good way is making just a bean for getting requested images.

Second, your varible "brand_image" need to be a object of DefaultStreamedContent. Because you are using primefaces.

```
brand_image = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, "image/jpeg");
```