# Need to refresh java web project on tomcat server when new images get uploaded in my web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have created java web application and deployed on tomcat server. When project is running I am coping images from outer source to my web project folder.

The issue I am facing here is each time I need to refresh my project structure manually when coping is done to see those images in my project deployeed on tomcat server.

Is there any alternative way than manually to see those changes automatically as soon as image coping is done.

Comment: can you elaborate what `I need to refresh my project structure manually` means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it with 2 way... First way in a client side - when adding new information to the server add it with js to client side too...

second way is in below link- (Creating FileSystem out of the project - Because project runs inside Application Server))

[Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)