# JSF Displaying images only just after page refresh

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am having weird problem with displaying images on my JSF application. They're not visible after page is rendered first time, but after at least one refresh they're visible.

I've developed images upload feature, and I'm saving uploaded images to

```
web\resources\files\
```

directory located under my JSF project.

Here's my view code, which should display for each uploaded file thumbnail with hyperlink to it. (festivalViaFile.images is my String array with images name with extensions saved during previous upload phase)

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox" id="lighbox1">  
    <ui:repeat value="#{festivalViaFile.images}" var="image">
        <h:outputLink value="resources/files/#{image}" title="#{festivalViaFile.festival.name}">                                           
            <h:graphicImage library="files" name="#{image}" style="height: 120px; width: 180px; margin: 5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888" />  
        </h:outputLink>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:lightBox>
```

When I open developer tools, Chrome gives me this as image code:

```
<img id="j_idt60:0:j_idt62" src="RES_NOT_FOUND" alt="" style="height:
120px; width: 180px; margin: 5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888">
```

After refreshing page it looks like:

```
<img id="j_idt60:0:j_idt62" src="/piaproject/faces/javax.faces.resource/1487053141410.jpeg?ln=files" alt="" style="height: 120px; width: 180px; margin: 5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888">
```

Feel free to request any additional information.

**SOLVED:** [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)

Change glassfish's xml file and change upload desination. 
Full post in link provided.

Comment: did you try to use the primefaces `graphicImage` componente ?!?

Comment: it will look like `<p:graphicImage id="img" name="/images/#{image}" >
                                        </p:graphicImage>`

Comment: In addition i think the image link `web\resources\files\` is wrong in my example the root folder of  `images` is ressource please consider trying remove `web\resources\` .

Comment: Yes. No difference at all when using primefaces library.

Comment: Do you have idea why this problem solves itself after page refresh?

Comment: it can be anything i am supposing there is a problem with the `id` (graphicImage ) we will try to solve this problem

Comment: try to remove the `h:outputLink` and work without it and change the image path like i said before

Comment: @YagamiLight Again same problem, image reveals just after page refresh.

Comment: try to remove the `library` element in the `graphicImage` ???

Comment: I've tried with code you provided me without library tag, still nothing.

Comment: Let's make it simple remove every thing and restart with a simple `graphicImage` with a simple path and see what is happening (remove lightbox everything ...)