# Uploaded images only viewable in Azure Web Apps for Linux after server restarted

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

My Azure Web Apps for Linux application successfully allows a user to upload images.
The images are successfully stored in a directory BankScans.

I try and display the image in the browser:

```
<img width="516" height="730" class="theCanvas img-fluid" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transition:none; cursor: move; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" draggable="false"
src="BankScans/f79f76bf-a4f1-4495-1234-91c97d6a70bd.jpg">
```

The images are not displayed. However if I restart the Azure Web Apps for Linux, then the images will be displayed.

Any idea how I can allow the user to see the images, without the need to first restart the Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as @BalusC's answer in [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096)

In a nutshell, uploaded images should not be saved in the deployment folder.

In my case, just changing the directory of the BankScans directory to be outside the deployment folder solved the problem, and no extra configuration of Tomcat was necessary.