# how to invoke jsp page from my index.html file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to invoke my jsp page from my index.html.This is html code.

```
 <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            </head>
            <form action="DownloadFile.jsp">
                <body>
                     <div>Click here Download File from Server...</div>
                     <input type="submit" name="downloadButton" value="Download..." />
                </body>
            </form>
    </html>

JSP PAGE:

    <%

                    String filename = "Sample1.zip"; 
                    String filepath = "e:\\temp\\"; 
                    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"); 
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""); 

                    java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath + filename);

                    int i; 
                    while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(i); 
                    } 
                    fileInputStream.close();
            %>
```

But When i pressing Download Button, it just shows the jsp file content as html.it does not start downloading the file anyway. What is the problem here...

and also i cann't download .docx and .jpg files correctly.It says file may be corrupted...

Please Guide me to get out of this both issues...

Is there a common way to download all types of files in jsp?

Comment: As to *"Is there a common way to download all types of files in jsp?"*, head to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1812244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server either does not support JSP or is not configured for it.

You need a JSP capable server.

Comment: i am using netbeans7 and tomcat 7.But i can able to run jsp file by directly put the path in browser...

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the Servlet engine with you webserver and done the setup for forwarding request for jsp files to server engine.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you do not need jsp to download you content . Instead, if you want to download from the client end, you can use html5

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the below hyperlink to download the any such file:<p>

<a href="5.csv" download>
test
</a>
```

Comment: In OP's case, file is not located in public web content. Your answer assumes so.