# Providing static data out of web application

Tags: java, web-applications, static-content

I have two machines that will be an application server in each.
The machine X is dynamic sources. The machine Y is static sources.

Thus, the user is always connected to "x.com".
When he does one upload an image, I need to send this information to "y.com".
How can I pass (at the time of upload) the byte image server x.com to save on y.com ?

See here what I started doing:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30239&p=96776#p96776

Balusc answered very well here:
[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

But my case is slightly diferent.

I appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to create a database table on X.com to track all images your user store on Y.com, for example:

```
+----------+-------------------------+
| user_id  |       image_path        |
+----------+-------------------------+
|       0  | /images/image_xxxxx.jpg |
|       0  | /images/image_xxxxx.jpg |
|       2  | /images/image_xxxxx.jpg |
|       2  | /images/image_xxxxx.jpg |
|       3  | /images/image_xxxxx.jpg |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

and then serve on X.com all your images redirecting the browser to Y.com

```
X.com:

<img src="Y.com/images/image.xxxxx.jpg" />
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I intend to do! But how can I pass (at the time of upload) the byte image server x.com to save on y.com/images/?

Comment: you have 2 ways:
you can upload directly to X.com, record upload, and then pass the image to Y.com. otherwise you can upload to Y.com, which for every upload send a request to X.com letting him know he received an image (you can use a simple Json, and ssl for better security). the first method is simpler to implement, the second drains less bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Use share network disk like: samba or NFS.
Ootionaly you can consider to setup rsyncs if you have Linux/U*x hosts