# How to write sequence of Bson to file with MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

Using the MongoDB Java Driver library is there a way to stream writes of bson objects to a file and then later stream reads of bson objects from that file. Looking at the documentation I see nothing about how to encode a sequence of bson objects to a file similar to having a sequence of json objects in a file.

Comment: This might be helpful https://jaihirsch.github.io/straw-in-a-haystack/mongodb/2014/09/16/generate-bson-files-with-java/

Comment: and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689874/how-could-i-write-a-bsondocument-object-into-a-file-and-read-it-again-using-ja

Comment: Writing/reading bson objects is what the driver already does.. and the file it uses is the data file. Mongo is a document database, everything is bson document. So if you have the bson object, or a sequence of objects, using the driver, you can persist it in the db file. What else is the db for?

Answer (score 2):

***MongoDB GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files.***

Use **GridFS** to store a file « GridFS uses two collections to save a file to a database: fs.files and fs.chunks. Based on the size of the file the data get stored into multiple individual “chunks”.
 * MongoDB Files using GridFS. [`Refer to MyPost`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544285/5081877)

For more information on GridFS go through my [Github wiki](https://github.com/Yash-777/mongo-java-driver/wiki/MongoDB-Files).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    mongoDB_GRIDFS("D:\\Yash\\JavaCSV.csv");
}
public static void mongoDB_GRIDFS(String csvlocation) throws IOException{
    Mongo Mongo = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 ); // Connect to MongoDB
    DB db = Mongo.getDB( "DBName" ); // Get database
    String bucketName = "BucketName";
    GridFS gridFs = new GridFS(db,bucketName); //Create instance of GridFS implementation  
    String imageName = "image1";
    upload(gridFs, csvlocation, imageName);
    download(gridFs, imageName);     
    Mongo.close();
}
public static void upload(GridFS gridFs, String csvlocation, String imageName) throws IOException{
    GridFSInputFile gridFsInputFile = gridFs.createFile(new File(csvlocation));
    gridFsInputFile.setId("777");
    gridFsInputFile.setFilename(imageName); //Set a name on GridFS entry
    gridFsInputFile.save(); //Save the file to MongoDB
}
public static void download(GridFS gridFs, String imageName) throws IOException{
    GridFSDBFile outputImageFile = gridFs.findOne(imageName);
    String outcsvLocation = "D:\\Yash\\mongoCSV.csv";//Location of the file read from MongoDB to be written
    outputImageFile.writeTo(new File(outcsvLocation));
}
```

[image: Grid FS]

---

**CSV file to JSON Object and JSON String to CSV File.**

- CSV file to JSON <sup>[refer to *class* `CSV_FileOperations`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48563857/5081877)</sup>.
- JSON to CSV File <sup>[refer to *method* `Json2Csv(String fileName, String jsonString)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544285/5081877)</sup>.

---

**JSON to BSON and BSON to JSON.**

[MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)<sup>[jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.14.2)</sup> comes with utility methods for parsing JSON to BSON and serializing BSON to JSON.

- BSON Library « A standalone BSON library, with a new Codec infrastructure that you can use to build high-performance encoders and decoders without requiring an intermediate Map instance.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261133/5081877).

```java
DBObject dbObj = new Document("myKey", "myValue");
String db_json = com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize( dbObj );

DBObject bson = ( DBObject ) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse( jsonData );
System.out.println("BSON Object : "+ bson);
```

sample output:

```
BSON Object : [ { "Key2" : "21" , "Key1" : "11" } , { "Key2" : "22" , "Key1" : "12"}]
Json : {"K1":"V1","K2":"V2"}
Map : {K1=V1, K2=V2}
```

Comment: How would you see with mongo shell where the file was stored?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documention for [MongoDb Java driver: BSON](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/bson/) I wrote following example. Is this what you are looking for?

Class for the logic:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.bson.BsonBinaryReader;
import org.bson.BsonBinaryWriter;
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.StringCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;
import org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer;

public class Bson {

    FileOutputStream fop;
    FileInputStream fip;
    BsonWriter writer;
    BsonReader reader;
    Codec<Person> codec;
    EncoderContext ec;
    DecoderContext dc;
    BasicOutputBuffer output;

    public Bson() {
        PojoCodecProvider provider = PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                .register(Person.class)
                .build();

        CodecRegistry registry = CodecRegistries
                .fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new StringCodec()),
                        CodecRegistries.fromProviders(provider));
        codec = provider.get(Person.class, registry);
        ec = EncoderContext.builder().build();
        dc = DecoderContext.builder().build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bson bson = new Bson();
        // write data
        bson.initBsonWriter();
        bson.encodePerson(new Person("John", "Doe"));
        bson.encodePerson(new Person("John2", "Doe2"));
        bson.encodePerson(new Person("John3", "Doe3"));
        bson.closeFop();

        // read data
        bson.initBsonReader();
        Person person = bson.decodePerson();
        System.out.println(person);
        person = bson.decodePerson();
        System.out.println(person);
        person = bson.decodePerson();
        System.out.println(person);
        bson.closeFip();
    }

    public void initBsonWriter() throws IOException {
        openFop();
        output = new BasicOutputBuffer();
        writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(output);
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeName("values");
        writer.writeStartArray();
    }

    public void initBsonReader() throws IOException {
        openFip();
        reader = new BsonBinaryReader(ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(fip)));
        reader.readStartDocument();
        reader.readName();
        reader.readStartArray();
    }

    public void encodePerson(Person p) {
        codec.encode(writer, p, ec);
    }

    public Person decodePerson() {
        return codec.decode(reader, dc);
    }

    public void openFop() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("example.bson");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    public void closeFop() throws IOException {
        writer.writeEndArray();
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        output.pipe(fop);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
    }

    public void openFip() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("example.bson");
        fip = new FileInputStream(file);
    }

    public void closeFip() throws IOException {
        fip.close();
    }
}
```

POJO to store some data:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person() { }

    public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName) {  
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if there is more than one bson object written to the file?

Comment: I modified the example. Now is in file created one main document containing an array of `Person` objects. I used `wirter`to create the main document so you can easily stream objects to the array.

Comment: @user782220 now when my example supports streaming multiple BSON object to the file, is it what you are looking for? Or did I missed something?