# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: glassfish

I've problem with code for downloading file from the server. It looks like this:

```
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("audio/vnd.wave");
    File file = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    long toWrite = file.length();
    filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, filename.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    //response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(toWrite));
    response.setContentLength((int)toWrite);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
    //Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    byte data[] = new byte[1024*1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = stream.read(data)) > 0) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(data, 0, len);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.flushBuffer();
        toWrite -= len;
        System.out.println("left="+toWrite+" "+w.getBufferSize()+" "+w.getBytes().length);
    }
    stream.close();
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    context.responseComplete();
```

For files over 1GB it ends with OOME (this one has about 1.4GB):

```
[#|2016-12-12T14:41:40.350+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=99;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|left=389066752 8192 10737
41824|#]

[#|2016-12-12T14:41:41.237+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=99;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|#{showContractBean.downloadReco
rding(item2.recFile)}: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
javax.faces.FacesException: #{showContractBean.downloadRecording(item2.recFile)}: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsResponseWrapper$MyServletOutputStream.write(ExtensionsResponseWrapper.java:141)
        at com.agreeya.telekonferencje.web.ShowContractBean.downloadRecording(ShowContractBean.java:1569)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
```

Server has fixed 4GB memory for the domain, NewRatio is set to 2 (the default value).
As you can see I've tried so far:
1. More memory for glassfish
2. Smaller/bigger buffer array
3. Flush response and output stream after each write
4. Set ContentLength to file size
5. Copy streams directly (FileStream -> OutputStream)
6. Set Content-Length directly as header
with no luck. The output should be streammed but it's not.

Is there something else what should i try?

At the moment upgrading GF to 4 is not possible, I'm affraid.

|| EDIT

Finally it's working as expected:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
ExtensionsResponseWrapper responseWrapper = (ExtensionsResponseWrapper)response;
HttpServletResponse delegateResponse = responseWrapper.getDelegate();

try {
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("audio/vnd.wave");
    File file = new File(filename);
    long toWrite = file.length();
    filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, filename.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(toWrite));
    response.setContentLength((int)toWrite);
    ServletOutputStream out = delegateResponse.getOutputStream();
    out.flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), out);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    context.responseComplete();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the class `ExtensionsResponseWrapper` writes the output into a ByteArrayOutputStream, see the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk12/1.1.14/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/filter/ExtensionsResponseWrapper.java#126).

I don't know if this is standard MyFaces response, or it is used because of some configuration in your app / GlassFish. Review the code that creates / receives the `response` object.

Comment: Seems like ByteArrayOutputStream.flush() is no-op and there is no way to make it streaming. And I was missing [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505635/buffering-response-in-heap-space-cause-problems-for-large-files). Thank you for the help.