# Tomcat seems to ignore new <Context> element in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, context.xml

after reading various questions about how to handle images on tomcat I followed the approach to set a folder with images at tomcat following the instructions here:
[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356) but it doesn't work and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I've set the context in server.xml as described:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">



    <Context docBase="C:\ServerFiles\" path="/images" />


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
```

and I also tried this:

```
    <Context docBase="C:\ServerFiles" path="/images" />
```

instead of the above.

The image is located at

`C:\ServerFiles` and its name is `index.jpg`

and this is how i try to retrieve it with jsf

```
<img src="/images/index.jpg" />
```

but it doens't work

Can you help me? I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using an IDE capable of taking over control from server, like Eclipse? If so, then you should be editing `server.xml` file in IDE's *Servers* project instead. Otherwise, you need to reconfigure the IDE to not take over control from server, but just use it directly (including all of its configuration files which you edited externally outside control of the IDE).

Comment: @BalusC I didn't know that. I am using eclipse which does what you say. So I should edit the file at the servers->Server-name->server.xml right? I am just curious I've edited the server.xml at the config folder of the ApacheTomcat in order to support https and it worked fine, though I didn't edited the server.xml at the eclipse. Aren't those two equivalent?

Comment: Both ways of editing server.xml are correct. If I understand it correctly if you modify the config folder inside tomcat, the changes are global, whereas your changes to eclipse's server.xml only affect the embedded tomcat in the IDE.

Comment: @BalusC you are right, I changed it in the server.xml of the eclipse and it worked. Perfectly.

Comment: You apparently changed to HTTPS before adding the server in Eclipse. Eclipse basically creates a copy of the "current" config. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If editing Tomcat's `server.xml` (or `context.xml` or `web.xml` or what not which resides in its `/conf` folder) appears to have no effect, then it's a strong hint that you're using an IDE which has taken over the control from Tomcat. Eclipse for example does that by default. When you add Tomcat server in Eclipse, then it basically creates a copy of its `/conf` folder into the IDE's *Servers* project, uses the IDE workspace as deploy space and solely uses Tomcat server's engine to run projects against the config in *Servers* project and deployments inside workspace.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Edit the configuration files in *Servers* project instead.
2. Tell Eclipse to *not* take over control from Tomcat but instead use (and manipulate!) it directly. Doubleclick the Tomcat entry in *Servers* view, select in the section *Server location* the option *Use Tomcat installation*.

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

The way you've defined Context should work. I cross checked a project where I do this and I didn't see any issue on your `server.xml`.

Maybe you have a separate `context.xml` in the `METAINF` folder of your web module that overrides the setting here.

BTW the second example **without** the trailing `\` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: No, the META-INF exists only a file named MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Hmm.. Can you try accessing your index.jpg by fully qualifying it.. I mean with the whole server name etc and see if you can access it..