# Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Grails application

Tags: grails, external, static-content

[This ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java) is so smilar to this ticket . However , we want to know where to put this tag if we have a grails project structure:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/images" path="/images" />
```

Otherwise , if we want to take advantages of grails features , is it enough to program action like that

```
def ResourceConroller{
      static dir='/usr/share/lib/'
      def getImg(){
        def name=params?.name
        render(contentType:"image/png"){
          //What we should write here : might us convert image to bytes !? .. NO IDEA
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The absolute simplest way to do this would be to use the `grails install-templates` command then modify the `src/templates/war/web.xml` to contain the new virtual directory/context path.