# Managing user images in spring web application

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Please spare me if my question sound naive, but I have a doubt regarding managing a large no. of images uploaded by user, for an instance I have a web application which allows user to upload multiple images which are stored on disk (lets say /opt/images/multiple_folders_containing_multiple_images), but when I refer it on my HTML code then the images are not loaded.

Can anyone please suggest what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: When I load HTML the image is not loading, I think the the images should be hosted on server as well.

Comment: firstly you have to checked image is uploaded properly or not ? then check the src of the image. check the path from where you retrieve the image.

Comment: The image gets uploaded successfully, but the confusion is where should i store them, shall I store them in the application folder deployed over tomcat or somewhere else on disk?

Answer (score 0):

I've came across some possible solutions:-

1) [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

2) Introduce a Apache server and host your image folder and then refer the static content, the benefit of using this is that, it is scale-able and can be easily migrated.

If anyone have better solution, then please do post.