# Import jsp and html pages from outside the webapp project

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to import several jsp and html pages in one single jsp page in spring mvc. I have added the docbase in server.xml of apache tomcat as

```
<Context docBase="/Users/uname/Desktop path="statfiles" />
<Context docBase="BankFeed" path="/helloweb" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BankFeed"/></Host>
```

but when i am import the file in my jsp page

```
<c:import var="testfile" url="/statfiles/test.html" />
<c:out value="${testfile}" />
```

I am getting this warning

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helloweb/statfiles/test.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

How can i resolve this issue and how to get the jsp and html pages outside the webapp project folder.

This is the directory Structure
[image]

Comment: Can you post your Directory Structure !!

Comment: I have added the image of directory structure

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a spring-mvc way, and add a mapping for static resources, with location prefixed with *file:*

so

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/statfiles/**" location="file:/Users/uname/Desktop/" />
```

in SpringMVC the prefix inside the location instructs the lookup strategy, and there are four types

```
classpath: - resources loaded from the classpath.
file: - resources loaded as a URL, from the filesystem.
http: - resources loaded as a URL.
(none) - resources relative to the ROOT
```

You can read more about configuring static resources in Spring MVC here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html