# Java Web uploaded image doesn't shown

Tags: java, image, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using tomcat 8 and uploading image to server by this code:

```
public static String uploadImage(String description, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        Part filePart;
        try {
            filePart = request.getPart(PARAM_NAME_IMAGE);
            try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH + description + ".jpg"));
                InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream()){
                int read;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = fileContent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IOException", e);
        }
        return PATH_TO_IMAGE + description + ".jpg";
    }
```

Then i save image path to DB for my item. And then i want to see it on the page by using:

```
<img src="${item.imagePath}" width="350" height="320" />
```

[But here is what I see](https://pp.vk.me/c622030/v622030390/396a2/8OIFEjiuuXY.jpg)

[And then if I restart server everything is ok and its shown](https://pp.vk.me/c622030/v622030390/396a9/rMVnsXN1Lso.jpg)

So, I need to see what I upload without restarting server

Answer (score -1):

Is your HTTP WEB Server and your Java Server container (Servlet or Enterprise container) configured that your request is a Multipart Request? multipart/form-data specification (RFC-2388). I would iterate through the form-data after getParts on the Request.

Comment: thx, I added allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" to Tomcat context.xml, but didnt helped

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works after restarting the server.

Comment: @BalusC i read that i need to Store my image anywhere in an accessible location except of the IDE's project folder aka the server's deploy folder, but how to put path to image in <img src="???"  /> ?

Comment: Just read the duplicate answer from top to bottom, including the "See also" links.

Comment: @BalusC thank you very much, this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812356/4383709 helped

Comment: @BalusC now I have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620161 problem, maybe you can help?