# Load html , js, css files from file system and outside the sever

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I want to load html , js, css files from file system while running tomcat 7. 
Tried the following approach, and none of it works. 
1) put

```
<Context docBase="D:\temp\uploads\myfile" path="/MySharedHTML"/>
```

under `conf/server.xml`

2) created folder `conf\Catalina\localhost` and put `ROOT.xml` under it with following content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="D:\temp\uploads\myfile" path="/MySharedHTML"/>
```

when i tried to test my code with the following jsp file with tomcat running, nothing showed up

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>da
<c:import url="/MySharedHTML/extraweb.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Thank you

I have update my code by using controller to load html file and it works, but
the related js, css and image does not load.

Please give some suggestions, and the code is shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/photo" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void uploadPhoto(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    // String filename =
    // URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo().substring(1), "UTF-8");
    String filename = "tour.html";
    File file = new File("D:/temp/uploads/myfile", filename);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", servletContext.getMimeType(filename));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
}
```

sever.xml in tomcat

```
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
           <Context docBase="D:\temp\uploads\vtour" path="/MySharedHTML"/>

  </Host>
```

Comment: [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812356/4290096) ?

Comment: @JAVY i tried to <Context docBase="D:\temp\uploads\myfile" path="/MySharedHTML"/> as I mention, it does not work, and I already read the post you referred

Comment: tried with the FileServlet as mentioned in the answer ? or just this xml tag in server.xml ?

Comment: @JAVY just xml tag in server.xml, since i want to keep it simple first

Comment: @JAVY I tried servlet and it load html well, but how to load the related js, css and images , :( , any suggestions?

Comment: may be you should add your code, so that everyone can see and help you :).

Comment: @JAVY added java code.

Comment: You are using `filename = "tour.html";` for outputstream , is that an issue or just used here as an example ? `String name` is not used anywhere !

Comment: @JAVY it is just example , and tour.html contains many js, css and images. those file can not be loaded. any suggestions?

Comment: For Eg: js is included in your html file like this ? `<script src="/photo/test.js"></script>`

Comment: @JAVY yes, that is my code

Comment: @JAVY the reason to use such approach is because those files are generated in the file system while application running.

Comment: OK ,I tried this -  `http://localhost:8084/MySharedHTML/test.js` even works without Servlet, let me try with a Servlet.

Comment: @JAVY, ok, i got no luck on that. I used servlet instead.

Comment: @JAVY for http://localhost:8084/MySharedHTML/test.js, did you put <context in server.xml ?

Comment: Yes , `<Context docBase="/home/user/webShare" path="/MySharedHTML" />` , inside `<Host>` tag.

Comment: @JAVY I tried the same set up, and does not work at all. is the sever.xml located in conf in tomcat? which version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: Yes inside conf, but the version is new (8.0.15 ).

Comment: i have post my sever.xml above, can you see any errors?

Comment: no , looks ok to me.