# web.xml vs websocket in tomcat 8

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, web.xml

I'm learning sockets in java Tomcat. I have running tutorial example like:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo") 
public class EchoServer {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
       System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session " + session.getId() + " has ended");
    }
}
```

and a proper html file connecting to this socket via javascript. My problem is in web.xml, which I understood not to have influence for socket handling. However having web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
 <display-name>SocketPOC</display-name>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My socket stops working. When I delete servlet-mapping flags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
 <display-name>SocketPOC</display-name>

</web-app>
```

it works back again. I would like to have it both - like I would like to server html files via this server and handle sockets in parallel. What am I doing wrong?

Tomcat version 8.0.33
jre 1.9.0_91
I'm running it under eclipse Luna (if it changes anything).

Comment: Just a short notice, that static can be served via <context> entry in server.xml (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java), also I have a apache before tomcat (so that's another layer to serve static context). Finally I could implement a class to serve it too. However still I would like to understand what is wrong with <servlet-mapping> attribute in web.xml (as I thought web.xml has no influence on websockets).

Comment: I believe 'default' is reserved for the default servlet, unless you're going to provide the same functions plus more. Try something else.

Answer (score 1):

As you remark the Servlet and Websocket API are mostly independent and there might even be [standalone WebSocket containers](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/2.0/websocket-spec-2.0.html#application-deployment-in-standalone-websocket-server-containers).

When a container offers both the Servlet API and Websocket API, the Websocket implementations usually relies on the Servlet implementation and some restrictions might arise.

Tomcat's websocket implementation installs a `Filter` ([`WsFilter`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsFilter.java)) bound to `/*` in your application. This filter intercepts all requests and if they match a websocket `Endpoint` it redirects it to the endpoint.

However the **filter** will only be called if there is a **servlet** willing to process the request. Usually the `default` servlet processes all requests that are not processed by other servlets, but you changed its URL pattern to `*.html`. All requests, whose URI does not end up in `.html` (like `/echo`) will not even be routed to your application and they will receive a non-customized `404 Not Found` error.

Since there is no reason to change the binding of the `default` servlet (all resources that should not be accessible on the web, should be in the `/WEB-INF` folder anyway), the issue in your question is more of a curiosity than a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I got it to work renaming the servlet to "default2" instead like

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

using a tomcat 8.5.57