# How to get access to the static file out of webapp(somehow the web application directory)?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have tried this [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356). I add this to my server.xml(`D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\conf`)Inside the`<Host>` tag . But it did not work.

```
<Context docBase="C:\java workspace\picture" path="/images" />
```

I think if it because I am using the Intellij idea?  Because the idea will create a new instance of tomcat at `C:\Users\lxa\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\_drill_3\conf`? I can not change the web.xml of the `C:\Users\lxa\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\_drill_3\conf`

Answer (score 0):

From`Run/Debug Configurations` Select `Startup/Connection` and then check `Pass environment variables` and add a new entry: `CATALINA_BASE` with your Tomcat address