# .war file is too big (600mb) because of videos

Tags: spring-boot, war

I have small videos total of 540mb in src/resources/static. Is being too big a problem for .war file? I will deploy it to tomcat now. If it is a problem, how can I solve this problem? Because I cannot play local videos from javascript (with file:///) at Chrome. Hence, I must put them at the project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the videos out to a separate location on the server:

[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

Or you could host them on another service (AWS S3?) and provide an endpoint to proxy them

Comment: I am using digitalocean 5$ droplet currently.

Comment: thanks, I got the idea from the best answer from the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
package com.youtalkwesign.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@Controller
public class VideoController {

@GetMapping("sign-videos/{word}")
protected void doGet(@PathVariable String word, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("home/sign-videos/" + word + ".mp4"); // TODO: D:/sign-videos/ or home/sign-videos/
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
}
}
```