# Spring URL mapping question

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I am using Java with Spring framework.  Given the following url:

```
www.mydomain.com/contentitem/234
```

I need to map all requests that come to `/contentitem/{numeric value}` mapped to a given controller with the "numeric value" passed as a parameter to the controller.

Right now in my servlet container xml I have simple mappings similar to the following:

```
...
<entry key="/index.html">
   <ref bean="homeController" />
</entry>
...
```

I am just wondering what I need to add to the mapping in order to achieve what I described?

**Edit**: I unaccepted the answer temporarily because I can't seem to figure out how to do the mapping in my web.xml (I am using annotations as described in axtavt's answer below).  How do I add a proper `<url-pattern>..</url-pattern>` in my `<servlet-mapping>` so that the request for "/contentitem/{numeric_value}" gets properly picked up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using annotation-based controller configuration (see [15.3 Implementing Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)):

```
@Controller
public class ContentItemController {

    @RequestMapping("/contentitem/{id}")
    public ModelAndView contentItem(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but my project is currently set up without annotations.  Any way I could get the solution without using annotations?

Comment: No. There is no ways configure extraction of path variables without annotations.

Comment: really?? wow, thats surprising to me...okay thanks for ur help!

Comment: hmm..when I try to add the @Controller annotation I get the following error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Controller to Annotation"  not sure why this is...

Comment: Check your `import` s. `Controller` interface is `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller`, `@Controller` annotation is `org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`.

Comment: @es11: For mapping options, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129876/using-spring-mapping-to-root-in-web-xml-static-resources-arent-found/2129960#2129960

Answer (score 3):

try to use @RequestMapping and @PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(value="/contentitem/{value}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String demo(@PathVariable(value="nvalue") String name, ModelMap map) {

int intValue = Integer.parseInt(nvalue);

// Do manipulation

return "something"; // Forward to something.jsp
}
```

Watch this [Spring MVC Framework Tutorial](http://youtu.be/Q6hZQ5SzGyM)

Answer (score 0):

You must import `org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`.