# How to browse htm file in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, glassfish

I am using default configuration of Spring MVC 2. So, my dispatcher will look like,

```
 <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
```

I have a simple htm file on root. When I browse this file I get 404:Not Found Error. How to browse (**which exist physically on disk**) htm file in Spring MVC.

Comment: This question has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129876/using-spring-mapping-to-root-in-web-xml-static-resources-arent-found

Comment: See my answer below, also if possible provide the entry in your web.xml for dispatcher servlet. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In annotation based Spring 3.x, you can just write it in your controller as,

```
@RequestMaping(value="/index.htm")
public void doSomeJob(){
    //some code here
}
```

and if you make a request as "/pathToIt/index.htm", then it will be caught by doSomeJob() method..

P.S No need for request mappings in configuration files in Spring MVC 3.x

Note: And also 404 can be caused if spring can't find your physical file..

Comment: Thanks but I am using MVC 2 and the problem is that I have a physical *.htm file but Spring is claiming 404 Not Found.

Comment: Can you post your project directories & files..and also servlet configuration contents (where you defined your viewResolvers etc. if you have any) and controller part that receives your index.htm request..

Comment: See and download the project, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861401/404-error-when-i-click-insert-image-link-in-tinymce-editor

Answer (score 1):

Try and add a bean id in your springmvc-servlet.xml file :

```
<bean id="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
```

then :

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
        <props>
               ...
           <prop key="/index.htm">indexController</prop>
         </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not solve my problem. When I remove web.xml setting(servlet-mapping) then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map URL `index.htm` with your controller. You cannot view your page until it will have correct spring mvc configuration.

```
<bean name="/index.htm" class="com.indexController">
 ....
</bean>
```

In controller you will pass your jsp page name as `view` in `modelAndView`.

Check your view resolver has correct setting like this

```
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: yes. change <value>.jsp</value> to <value>.htm</value> or add another value.

Comment: I am well aware about routing rules, both in Spring MVC and ASP.NET MVC. This is not a routing issue. The problem is that Dispathcher Serve catching all requests which are ends with .htm. I am looking some thing like, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx

Comment: add more url pattern in web.xml  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

Answer (score 1):

Ok this sounds familiar , if you are using MVC 2 then the best way to achieve this is to give a specific mapping for dispatcher servlet instead of /

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>myDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

> This will make sure the only requests to *.jsp will go dispatcher servet and rest will be handled by the container itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, all my controller are already mapped to *.htm. I cannot change this mapping.

Comment: This cannot be done. Either you have to change the file extension from htm to html or rename the simple htm to html file :(