# path to static resources for default servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm new to Java-Servlets (came from PHP-Zend) and im facing some problems to get static content (like js, css, ...).

So first here the folder structure of the project:

```
com.a.b.c.servlet
    bin
       com
          ...
             LoginServlet.class
             ResourceServlet.class
    resources
       languages
       templates
          login.html
       static
          css
             style.css
          js
             script.js
    src
       com
          ...
             LoginServlet.java
             ResourceServlet.java
    WebContent
       META-INF
       WEB-INF
```

First, i've wrote a Resource Servlet for getting the static content acting like this....

```
    InputStreamReader resource = new InputStreamReader(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/static" + request.getPathInfo()), "UTF-8");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    for ( int c; ( c = resource.read() ) != -1; )

        out.write(c);
    }
```

... but i have some trouble with images so i've looked for the best practice and found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129960/363323

Option 3 seems a good option to me, so i've added this lines to my web.xml (and removed the ResourceServlet mapping)

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But the resources aren't loaded... i tried several pathes like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

and also put the static folder on different places....

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to write a servlet to serve static resources? Why don't you just put the static resources in WebContent (and thus in the deployed app) directly?

Comment: unfortunally, this folder i didn't tried... thx, that's the solution