# Spring MVC Controller with SiteMesh

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I had an application that use sitemesh and spring mvc but the css and javascript cannot be applied.

```
15:13:38,745 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/default.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,750 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/jquery.jmover.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,748 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/jquery-updates.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,748 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,745 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/view.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,755 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.dataTables-1.7.5.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,755 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/jquery-ui.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,759 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.validate.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,753 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/menu.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,750 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/datatables.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,750 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/css/confirmationStyle.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,762 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.autocomplete.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,759 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.blockUI.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,764 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.selectboxes.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,757 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery-ui.core.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,763 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/dropmenu.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,763 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.jmover-1.2.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,843 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery-ui.core.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,859 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.blockUI.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,879 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.autocomplete.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,894 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.selectboxes.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,900 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/jquery.jmover-1.2.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
15:13:38,929 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SiteMesh/script/dropmenu.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I confirm that the sitemesh is working fine because when i change the url pattern the sitemesh is not working.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>SiteMesh</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <filter>
  <display-name>SiteMesh_Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>SiteMesh_Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SiteMesh_Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <listener>
  <display-name>Spring_Context_Loader_Listener</display-name>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <display-name>Spring_Dispatcher_Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My decorator layout JSP

```
<%@include file="../pages/init-page.jsp" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <title>
        <decorator:title default="IRM - Intelligent Routing Module" />
    </title>    

    <!-- CSS Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/view.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${context}/css/datatables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${context}/css/jquery.jmover.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${context}/css/jquery-updates.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${context}/css/confirmationStyle.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/menu.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.dataTables-1.7.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery-ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.selectboxes.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/script/jquery.jmover-1.2.js"></script>


    <decorator:head/>
</head>

<body>  

    <%-- Header --%>
    <%@include file="../pages/header.jsp" %>

    <c:if test="${sessionScope.user != null}">
        <%@include file="../pages/header.jsp" %>
    </c:if>
    <decorator:body/>

    <%-- Footer --%>
    <%@include file="../pages/footer.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that all the script and css from this jsp cannot be applied.

What wrong with it ?

Please help.

Comment: You should check two things: 1) Does Sitemash intercept the CSS files (I excpect it should not), 2) Does Spring allow access to the CSS files (when Sitemash does not intercept it/is disabled). Point 2) means: check your static resource handler mapping stuff.

Comment: I had added the static resources handler mapping but it still didn't work as expected. How to check Sitemesh is intercepts the CSS or script files ?

Comment: Disable the sitemash filter compleatly, if you then can access the css (direlty) it is a problem with your sitemash configuration.

Comment: I disable the sitemash filter completely and put this <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/view.css" type="text/css" />
</head> in the main page and sure that the css does not applied also. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding following tag in context xml. This will specify which directory contains the static resources. Change location as per your need.

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010977/spring-mvc-3-tiles-2-static-resources-are-not-displayed-even-in-non-tiles-pa) to learn more.

Comment: My css is located at WebContent/css and script is located at WebContent/script                                                                             <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/" />
<mvc:resources location="/script/" mapping="/" />

Comment: try : <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />

Comment: I disable the sitemash filter completely and put this <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/css/view.css" type="text/css" /> </head> in the main page and sure that the css does not applied also. Please help.