# Spring REST Service - Set the Root URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

New to spring and have a question regarding setting the Rest URI path.

I have a working rest service and I would like to change the URI from something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api` to `http://localhost:8080/api`

Normally I would do this with an annotation such as: @ApplicationPath("api") but that doesnt seem to be applicable, tried the below but doesnt give the desired result.

**TestController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public @ResponseBody Test Test() {
        return new Test("Test String");
    }
}
```

How can this be done with spring?

Comment: This might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129876/using-spring-mapping-to-root-in-web-xml-static-resources-arent-found

Comment: In addition to the other answers/comments here... Generally what you're trying to do isn't really a Spring thing, it's a servlet container (eg. Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, GlassFish, etc) configuration thing. More commonly, people proxy through Apache to hide the servlet name and port on the running Tomcat (using mod_proxy or mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally configured in META-INF/context.XML. Set path to / or "".

Here's a similar issue with tomcat 7

[HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)