# Getting 404 Not Found - while accessing valid REST service with Jersey + ExtJS

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, extjs

I am working on ExtJS and need to access the REST services. I tried doing that with Spring's MVC REST supporting functionality and it worked well.

Now its kind of mandatory that I have to go with Jersey(JAX-RS). When tried with Jersey, I keep getting 404 error. I think the annotations, URL mapping, etc are fine (since the similar ones worked for Spring)

Below are the relevant code snippets.

Web.xml

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.myProducts.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

App.js

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'Product',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'products',
            format: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            api: {
                create: 'products/createJ/',
                read: 'products/readJ/',
                update: 'products/editJ/',
                destroy: 'products/deleteJ/'
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller :

```
@Component
@Path("products/jersey/products")
public class JerseyProductsController {


    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @POST
    @Path("createJ/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Product createJ(@PathParam("id") int id, @RequestBody Product myProduct) {
        myProduct.setId(id);
        return productService.create(myProduct);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("editJ/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
    public Product editJ(@PathParam("id") int id, @RequestBody Product myProduct) {
        myProduct.setId(id);
        return productService.update(myProduct);
    }


    @DELETE
    @Path("deleteJ/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
    public Product deleteJ(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return productService.delete(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("readJ/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Product> allProductsJ() {
        return productService.getAll();
    }
}
```

I get 404 for below URL:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4080/MyProducts/products/jersey/products/readJ/.json?_dc=1407930853131&page=1&start=0&limit=25
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Kindly let me know what is being missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's the issue but you could try below one :

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

I believe its because it could capture requests ending with .do and it reduced the headache of having some pattern in between the URL.

Comment: Worked with *.do URL pattern!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use `/jersey/products/jersey` in your URL since you are having `<url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 1):

I think your servlet mapping is incorrect. Your Url-Pattern is /jersey/* but in your url is /MyProducts/*

put this in your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-jersey</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/MyProducts/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: MyProducts is my app name and /jersey/* - satisfies the condition for the URL that I am trying to access.

And the below one worked well for Spring :  

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-rest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-rest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

So I dont think that would be the issue. 
Btw I tried with many permutations (including the one you suggested) but no luck  :(

Comment: take a look at your url,

/MyProducts/ is your application,
products/jersey/products/ is your class,
/readJ/ is the method you want to call,

what you need is your /jersey/*

maybe it works with this url 
//localhost:4080/MyProducts/jersey/products/jersey/products/readJ/.json?_dc=1407930853131&page=1&start=0&limit=25